# Five Clues In Four lines

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, poetry

> Now with many
>   Now with having lovers
>   Now with first swing
>   Now with some covers

The words above constitute a riddle whose answer is a single English word. Find the word and explain the title.

Hint:

> Each of the four lines is a separate clue. It is also Socratic confusion

Hint:

> I added the wordplay tag because there is a pun involved.

Final hint:

> It's strange but I thought revealing that this is an acrostic would
>  make it too easy. Well, as hexomino figured out from the first hint,
>  an acrostic is what it is. Go with that. Acrost it. The other clues
>  will follow more easily unless I have again misjudged.

I will post a solution tomorrow. You have been warned. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In hindsight I should have lead off with the acrostic designation. I completely misjudged the difficulty of this riddle. Let me show you how I thought the reasoning was going to go.

Now with many

> Hmm. It goes with "many" lots of synonyms there.

Now with having lovers

> Cheating? Infidelities? Liaisons? Affairs? Unfaithful?
>  A forest of possibilities again. But not as big.

Now with first swing

> Here is where I hoped the reader could get his feet on the ground.
>  People seemed to get that this was sports-related. The sport where the first swing is a big deal is tennis. Or any racquet sport really. What I was going for was "serve" or "service". I omitted the article to tip it towards "service".

Now with some covers

> Some? What type of covers?

At this point I figured someone would put it together. Forgive me. Some of the answers here seemed superhuman to this newcomer. But I stuck in an acrostic because it appealed to my warped sense of humor. To solve the acrostic

> Take the first letter of each line

But... But... That doesn't...

> N N N N = 4N = foreign
>  Hence
>  Foreign Legion
>  Foreign Affairs
>  Foreign Service
>  Foreign Films
>
>  My comments often contain hints. Aced and let for tennis. Affair... Well, my heart was in the right place. Happy puzzling.

Comment: I'm shaking my fist at you, Hugh Meyers.

Comment: But in all seriousness, this was a good one. Glad you posted the answer, because, though you are under no obligation to do so, my own selfish curiosity was starting to get to me. I kept trying to come up with words that included the letters N-O-W and also involved those concepts, to no avail.

Comment: That's very clever. I think it would have taken me quite a long time to get it.

Comment: but you said that the answer was right on this page... :/

Comment: I meant the acrostic part. People were coming up with words that they could use to make an acrostic. I was trying to say that the letters for the acrostic were all on the page. And the acrostic was really all you strictly needed to solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 13):

I think the answer is

> Cast

Now with many

> Multicast, denoting a set of data sent across a computer network to many users at the same time.

Now with having lovers

> Opencast, denoting a method of mining and open corresponds to a non-monogamous relationship status

Now with first swing

> Forecast, denoting a prediction or estimate. 'Fore' is the call accompanying a golfer's swing.

Now with some covers

> Overcast, denoting cloud covering a large part of the sky. 'Over' is also some of the word 'covers'.

Fifth clue

> We can also read each clue without the 'now' to spell out a set of answers 
>   Many = **C** (100 in Roman numerals) 
>  Having lovers = **A**dulterous 
>  First swing = **S** (first letter of swing) 
>  Some covers = **T**ucked in 
>  These answers form an acrostic with the first letter of each answer combining to spell out the word **CAST**

Hint

> 'Socratic' is an anagram of acrostic (hence the confusion) which is the method used to spell out the answer in the last part.

Comment: I wish I could give you something more than just an up vote. Your reasoning is close and you aced the hint. I'm not sure the creators of opencast would appreciate being equated with adultery but that's your affair.

Comment: And I couldn't let this pass without mentioning that the third clue does refer to a sport, but not golf.

Comment: Ah yes, I did think when writing it down that it didn't resonate fully. I'll keep thinking.

Answer (score 3):

#### This is not a correct answer(my achievement)...confirmed by OP

I think it is

> [Mark Lowe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Lowe)

Now with many

> He previously played for the Seattle Mariners, Texas Rangers, Los Angeles Angels of Anaheim, Cleveland Indians, and Toronto Blue Jays.

Now with having lovers

> It is the pun on his last name I think as stated in hint 2.

Now with first swing

> It tells us that he is related to baseball

Now with some covers

> He is a relief pitcher. So we can say that he cover pitching for his team. (But I think it still needs better explanation)

Hint 1

> As already stated in the hint 3 that it's acrostic. So  **M**ANY H**A**VING FI**R**ST **C**OVERS... It gives us MARC, pronounced as MARK (as much as I know).

Comment: This is a neat interpretation!

Comment: When you see the solution, it may fill you with rage. The answer you seek is right on this page.

Comment: The sports reference is not baseball.

Answer (score 2):

Now with many

> A synonym for "many" is **C**OPIOUS

Now with having lovers

> Somebody who had a lover is **L**ADY CHATTERLEY

Now with first swing

> **U** is shaped like a [swing](http://thebrianmountjoy.typepad.com/.a/6a00e3981b770d8833017ee97ed232970d-800wi). Yes u is.

Now with some covers

> Part of a cover is the [**E**NVELOPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_(philately)).

So that fifth clue?

> It's the acrosticized version of all the answers.

Comment: "Now with" does indeed have significance.

Comment: @HughMeyers Well, I tried anyway.

Comment: You raised an important point.

Comment: @hugh now that I've changed my answer, I definitely don't know how it fits